# WPF CultureInfo in a combobox, DisplayName as DisplayMemberPath doesn't work when the SelectedUICulture is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, cultureinfo

I have written a small utility, in which the user can change the language. I put the available languages (as `CultureInfo`) in a `List<CultureInfo>`, bind it to a combobox and use the `DisplayMemberPath` to point to the `CultureInfo.DisplayName`.

```
private List<CultureInfo> languageOptions = new List<CultureInfo>();

public List<CultureInfo> LanguageOptions
{
    get { return languageOptions; }
    set
    {
        languageOptions = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("LanguageOptions");
    }
}
```

and in my constructor;

```
foreach (/* my available languages */)
{
   cultures.Add(new CultureInfo(/* language  ie.e en-US, de-DE etc */));
}
```

I use the following XAML to display the selected language:

```
<ComboBox  x:Uid="ComboBox_3" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding LanguageOptions}"
    DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default},
    Path=SelectedCulture}"/>
```

This works perfectly when the CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture are set to en-US.

[en-US example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mF0s.png)

When the user selects a new language, and restarts the utility, I set the `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` for the app in the App.xaml.cs as follows:

```
if ((TTSAutomate.Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedCulture)!=null)
{
    CultureInfo ci = TTSAutomate.Properties.Settings.Default.SelectedCulture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
}
```

This works perfectly, in that the utility is displayed in the correct language.
However, the combobox that displays the selected language, now only displays the `Name` of the CultureInfo, rather than the `DisplayName`.

[sk-SK example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgeIX.png)

Can anyone make a suggestion as to what is going on? I've tried `NativeName` instead, without any improvement

Answer (score 1):

I regenerated the satellite assemblies a few times (without changing anything), and 'suddenly' the binding started working :(